# Smoothness of Picard scheme when $H^2(\mathcal{O}_{X_s})$ on fibers vanish

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, picard-group

A question about the proof of *Proposition 5.19* in Kleiman's [notes on Picard scheme](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0504020). Let $X$ be a $S$-scheme. Then the claim is that:

> Assume that Picard scheme $\operatorname{Pic}_{X/S}$ exists and represents functor $\operatorname{Pic}_{(X/S)(\text{et})}$. Let
> $s \in S$ be a point such that $H^2(\mathcal{O}_{X_s}) = 0$. Then there exists an open neighborhood
> of $s$ over which  $\operatorname{Pic}_{X/S}$  is smooth.

Passing to approproate open subscheme $U \subset S$ we can assume that $H^2(\mathcal{O}_{X_t}) = 0$ holds for all $t \in S$.

The proof goes to use Infinitesimal Criterion for Smoothness [SGA 1, p. 67], it suffices to
show: given any $S$-scheme $T$ of the form $T = \operatorname{Spec}(A)$ where $A$ is an Artin local ring that is a finite $\mathcal{O}_s$-algebra and given any closed subscheme $T' \subset T$ whose vanishing ideal $I$ has square $0$ ( ie an infinitesimal thickering of order $2$), every $T'$-point of $\operatorname{Pic}_{X/S}$ lifts to a $T$ -point. We arive at following sequence

$$H^1(\mathcal{O}^*_{X_T}) \to H^1(\mathcal{O}^*_{X_R}) \to H^2(f_T^*I)$$

and by the intrinsic nature of Picard scheme & cocycle description of line bundles it suffice to show $H^2(f_T^*I)=0$.

As $T$ affine, $H^2(f_T^*I)=H^0(R^2f_{T*}f_T^*I)$, and then it is clamed that $R^2f_{T*}f_T^*I=0$ is consequence of assumption $H^2(X_t,\mathcal{O}_{X_t})=0$ for all $t \in S$ by Property of Exchange
[EGA III, **second** book, 7.7.5 II and 7.7.10].
Note, that fiberes after base change $T \to S$ not change.

**Question:** Why vanishing of the $H^2(X_t,\mathcal{O}_{X_t})$ imply this? The quoted base change property gives - so far I understand it correctly - information about the base change map

$$  R^2f_{T*}f_T^*I \otimes \kappa(t) \to H^2(X_t, j_t^* f_T^*I) $$

where $j_t: X_t \subset X_T$. But what does it (especially the right hand side) have to do with vanishing of $H^2(X_t,\mathcal{O}_{X_t})$? Clearly by construction the composition of $j_t$ with $f_T$ is a constant map, and eg if $I$ would be an invertible sheaf, we are done, because this would imply by assumptions that the right hand side is zero, and quoted EGA result would imply the same for the left term of the tensor product on the left.

But I not see any reason $I$ to be invertible sheaf (...since a local Artin ring can be non PID), so we cannot argue that $I$ pulled back along constant map $f_t \circ j_t$ is the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{X_t}$, or do I missing something at that point?

Therefore I not see how the assumed condition $H^2(X_t,\mathcal{O}_{X_t})=0$ is exploited here to conclude that $R^2f_{T*}f_T^*I$ is zero.

Does somebody see how this vanishing condition should be correctly applied here to deduce the claim?

Comment: $I$ need not be invertible, but it has a filtration by ideals $I_j$ such that $I_j/I_{j+1}$ is isomorphic to the residue field (as a module over the Artin ring). The vanishing then follows by considering the long exact sequence of cohomology associated to all triples of consecutive terms in this filtration. (This uses the assumption that $X$ is flat over $S$.)